# Change condition to add new address if no address save in customer My address book

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.3, address

I want to change the condition that redirect you to customer/address/new if you want to see your address book. I just want to open the address book empty without force users to add a new address in order to see the page. But can not find where change that condition in my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the steps below.

Assume you are using a custom module names "**Company_MyModule**"

**Step 1)**

Create **di.xml** under YOUR-MAGENTO-***ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc***

File : ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/di.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Index" type="Company\MyModule\Controller\Address\Index" />                    
</config>
```

**step 2)**

Create the controller file **Index.php** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Controller/Address***

File : ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Controller/Address/index.php***

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyModule\Controller\Address; 

class Index extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Index
{






   public function execute()
    {

        parent::execute();
        $addresses = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->_getSession()->getCustomerId())->getAddresses();
        //if (count($addresses)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('address_book');
            if ($block) {
                $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            }
            return $resultPage;
        //} 

    }    




}
```

**step 3)**

Run Di compile

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile